# Error in add settings and mappings via curl in shell script for elastic search

Tags: shell, elasticsearch, curl

I am trying to initialize settings and mappings via shell script in docker.

```
#!/bin/sh

until $(curl --output /dev/null --silent --head --fail http://elasticsearch:9200); do
    printf '.'
    sleep 5
done

for i in {30..0}; do
    if curl elasticsearch:9200; then
        curl -XPUT 'elasticsearch:9200/x_product/' -H 'Content-Type: application/json'  -d '{
                "settings": {
                   "number_of_shards": 1,
                   "analysis": {
                        "filter": {
                            "ngram_filter": {
                                "type": "nGram",
                                "min_gram": 2,
                                "max_gram": 3
                            }
                        },
                        "analyzer": {
                            "ngram_analyzer": {
                            "type": "custom",
                            "tokenizer": "my_tokenizer",
                            "filter":  ["lowercase", "ngram_filter"]
                            }
                        }
                    }
                },
                "mappings" : {
                    "product": {
                        "name": {
                            "type": "string",
                            "include_in_all": true,
                            "term_vector": "yes",
                            "index_analyzer": "ngram_analyzer",
                            "search_analyzer": "standard"
                        },
                        "description_value": {
                            "type": "string",
                            "include_in_all": true,
                            "term_vector": "yes",
                            "index_analyzer": "ngram_analyzer",
                            "search_analyzer": "standard"
                        },
                        "barcode_value": {
                            "type": "string",
                            "include_in_all": true,
                            "term_vector": "yes",
                            "index_analyzer": "ngram_analyzer",
                            "search_analyzer": "standard"
                        },
                        "searchword_content": {
                            "type": "string",
                            "include_in_all": true,
                            "term_vector": "yes",
                            "index_analyzer": "ngram_analyzer",
                            "search_analyzer": "standard"
                        },
                        "discount": {
                            "type": "integer"
                        },
                        "datetime": {
                            "type": "date",
                            "format": "epoch_millis"
                        }
                    }
                }
            }';
            break;
    fi
    sleep 2
done
```

However this syntax give me the error:

> {"error":{"root_cause":[{"type":"parse_exception","reason":"Failed to
>   parse content to map"}],"type":"parse_exception","reason":"Failed to
>   parse content to
>   map","caused_by":{"type":"json_parse_exception","reason":"Unexpected
>   character ('}' (code 125)): was expecting double-quote to start field
>   name\n at [Source:
>   org.elasticsearch.transport.netty4.ByteBufStreamInput@770de4a9; line:
>   19, column: 22]"}},"status":400}

What was wrong with my syntax?

Updated:
1. Update my syntax change "lowercase to "lowercase" also type to "type", however got another error 
2. Remove extra comma at analyzer

Comment: `"filter":  ["lowercase, "ngram_filter"]` you forgot `"` at the end of `"lowercase`. also, `type:` have to be `"type":`

Comment: Thank you, I have updated my syntax however still got another error:
{"error":{"root_cause":[{"type":"parse_exception","reason":"Failed to parse content to map"}],"type":"parse_exception","reason":"Failed to parse content to map","caused_by":{"type":"json_parse_exception","reason":"Unexpected character ('}' (code 125)): was expecting double-quote to start field name\n at [Source: org.elasticsearch.transport.netty4.ByteBufStreamInput@770de4a9; line: 19, column: 22]"}},"status":400}

Comment: paste your json to https://jsonlint.com/ and press "Validate JSON", and fix the error you get which has red line.

Answer (score 0):

Beside the syntax problem there is also problem in json fields for elastic search, so I change some fields and value, and also separate the settings and mappings to make it easier to read.

```
 curl -XPUT 'elasticsearch:9200/x_product/_settings' -H 'Content-Type: application/json'  -d '{
            "analysis": {
                "filter": {
                    "ngram_filter": {
                        "type": "nGram",
                        "min_gram": 2,
                        "max_gram": 3
                    }
                },
                "analyzer": {
                    "ngram_analyzer": {
                    "type": "custom",
                    "tokenizer": "standard",
                    "filter":  ["lowercase", "ngram_filter"]
                    }
                }
            }
        }';
        curl -XPUT 'elasticsearch:9200/x_product/_mapping/product' -H 'Content-Type: application/json'  -d '{
            "properties": {
                "name": {
                    "type": "text",
                    "term_vector": "yes",
                    "analyzer": "ngram_analyzer",
                    "search_analyzer": "standard"
                },
                "description_value": {
                    "type": "text",
                    "term_vector": "yes",
                    "analyzer": "ngram_analyzer",
                    "search_analyzer": "standard"
                },
                "barcode_value": {
                    "type": "text",
                    "term_vector": "yes",
                    "analyzer": "ngram_analyzer",
                    "search_analyzer": "standard"
                },
                "searchword_content": {
                    "type": "text",
                    "term_vector": "yes",
                    "analyzer": "ngram_analyzer",
                    "search_analyzer": "standard"
                },
                "discount": {
                    "type": "integer"
                },
                "datetime": {
                    "type": "date",
                    "format": "epoch_millis"
                }
            }
        }';
```